# Jmeter WebDriver Sampler - How to Select an Element from a table

Tags: jmeter, webdriver

So I'm using Jmeter WebDriver sampler and I have a table where each row has a Delete and Edit button.
The layout of the HTML table is as follows:

```
<tbody id=table_id>
 <tr>
   <td> name </td>
   <td>
     <a class="some random text" href="edit.php/20" role="button>edit>edit </a>
     <a class="some random text" onclick="delete20"> Delete </a>
   </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td> name2 </td>
   <td>
     <a class="some random text" href="edit.php/21" role="button>edit>edit </a>
     <a class="some random text" onclick="delete21"> Delete </a>
   </td>
 </tr>
```

I'm unsure how to tell the webdriver to click a button based on the product name without an ID to findByElementID. I was thinking maybe I can parse through the table but I'm unsure what the steps are to take that route.

Any advice would be much appreciated!
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

1. Identify the product by its name, i.e. `name` or `name2` using [text() function](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#location-paths)

   ```
   //td[text()=' name2 ']
   ```
2. Locate it's [following sibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes/following-sibling)

   ```
   //td[text()=' name2 ']/following-sibling::td
   ```
3. Locate the button which you want to click, i.e. "edit" or "delete"

   ```
   //td[text()=' name2 ']/following-sibling::td/a[text()=' Delete ']
   ```

Demo:

[image]

More information:

- [XPath Language Reference](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/)
- [XPath Tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp)
- [Using the XPath Extractor in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0)